# Ruby RPN Calculator: array of arrays, shift & to_i problems

Tags: ruby, arrays, class

I am making a Ruby Reverse Polish Notation calculator and could not find the answer to my problems in the archives.  I wrote a gameplan and am filling in the code.  My 3 current issues are:

- My array is an array of an arrays and I'm not sure why.  When I try this outside of a class it works okay.  Maybe it's something with how classes work?  I've watched a few videos are spent a few hours trying to understand characteristics of classes.
- When I try to move items to the new array, only one goes.  Perhaps this is tied in with the first issue.
- Converting my array element(s) to integers with to_i does not work in this context.  I can get it to work in other problems.  I am just starting with classes hence my many issues.  I am trying to learn regexp as well, since many other RPN calculators out there use it in their solutions - but I am not there yet in my understanding.

CODE:

```
class RPNCalculator
def initialize(problem)
    @problem = problem
end

def resolve
    array = []
    array << @problem.split(" ")
    operations = ["+", "-", "*"]
    queue = []
    @array = array
    @operations = operations
    @queue = queue
    p array  # => [["1", "3", "+"]] ISSUE #1: my test print shows array of an array.
# iterate through the array

array.each do |i|

# if array elements don't match a operations element, push them into the queue.

    if operations.include? i

# once you have a match on the function, launch a method
# make 3 new RPN methods, one each for + - *
# method launched should affect last 2 items in the queue.
# result of that method gets pushed to the end of the queue. 

    else queue.push(i.shift)
    end 
    queue.each { |x| x.to_i }
    p queue # => ["1"] ISSUE #2: only 1 was pushed in. Perhaps because issue #1?
                    #  ISSUE #3: my strings did not convert to integers.

end

# return the remaining value in the queue as the answer

end

# placeholder for method +
# placeholder for method -
# placeholder for method *

end

test = "1 3 +"
mytest  = RPNCalculator.new(test)
mytest.resolve
```

Comment: You might want to look at my answer to [this RPN question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345541/pulling-indexes-from-an-array-and-variable-scope/25346114#25346114) for ideas.

Comment: Please format your code properly, this is horrible to read. See https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide if you're unsure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ISSUE #1 > `[] << ["1", "3", "+"] #=> [["1", "3", "+"]]`

[#<<](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) inserts why not just initialize the Array with those elements? `arrray = ["1", "3", "+"]`

ISSUE #1.5 > `[["1", "3", "+"]].size #=> 1`

ISSUE #2 > `i = [["1", "3", "+"]].first #=> ["1", "3", "+"]`
so yes it's because of issue 1
ISSUE #2... > `i.shift #=> ["1"]`

ISSUE #3 #to_i or #each does not permanently modify the variable you need `queue.map!`
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-map-21

Comment: Why do `array = []`, then `array += some_stuff` instead of just `array = some_stuff`?